# Who decides the migration paths of questions?

Tags: discussion, flagging

Currently, if I flag a question as off-topic, I only have the option to recommend it goes to meta DB.

Will I ever be able to flag it as more appropriate for ServerFault or SO?

Answer (score 2):

One day, in the near future, migration paths will be assigned by the dev team. As a matter of fact, we *might* even be on the receiving end of a migration path from another stack. But for today, you pretty much just need to flag for a moderator if you want it migrated out. Additionally, we generally try and counsel with the other site when migration paths haven't been defined to *ensure* that it's on-target on the remote site.

They often are by that point, but we like to make sure.

Comment: migration paths are unlocked based on the "top 4" of *actual* migrations to and from the site -- based on the real world data.

Comment: Oh you and your facts Jeff. I was under the impression not all sites got four migration paths ;)

Comment: so..unlocked like achievements?

Comment: But site-global achievements.

Comment: Do you know at what point this will happen - or who we should ask? A migration path to SO at least would probably be handy.

Comment: I would ask RebeccaChernoff actually, or GraceNote. Might be a good learning Q for AarthiD, but I would put my money on RC giving a better response.

Comment: "near future"... it's now almost 6 years later and this feature still hasn't landed. Or has it?